# DateComponentsFormatter doesn't allow fractional units

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I can't make `DateComponentsFormatter` print out fractional units!

Here's the code in **Swift 4**:

```
let duration = 5400   // 1.5 hours in seconds

let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter.init()
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour]
dateComponentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
dateComponentsFormatter.allowsFractionalUnits = true
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .short

let stringDuration = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: number)
print(stringDuration!)
```

I've played around with `allowedUnits` and `maximumUnitCount`, but I can only make it print *"1 hr"* or *"2 hrs"*.

**How do I make in print *"1.5 hrs"*?**

Comment: Seems to be a known problem: http://www.openradar.me/32024200.